# how to use cp-react-tree-table in my project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to typescript, try to follow the demo https://www.npmjs.com/package/cp-react-tree-table to use this control in my project, but get below information.

Try to search and seems it's related to module definition which confuse.

Hope someone can show me light.

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import TreeDataTable from 'cp-react-tree-table';
```

'TreeDataTable' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Could not find a declaration file for module 'cp-react-tree-table'. 'path/node_modules/cp-react-tree-table/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try `npm install @types/cp-react-tree-table` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cp-react-tree-table';`ts(7016)
Could not find a declaration file for module 'cp-react-tree-table'. path/node_modules/cp-react-tree-table/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try `npm install @types/cp-react-tree-table` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cp-react-tree-table';`ts(7016)

Could not find a declaration file for module 'cp-react-tree-table'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file like *cp-react-tree-table.d.ts* then add the following content to resolve the error quickly, but it's unsafe.

```
    declare module "cp-react-tree-table" {
      let TreeDataTable: any;
      export default TreeDataTable;
    }
```

Also, make sure typescript honoring our declaration file.

Comment: Thanks, this will resolve compile error, while it's tough case to custom type definition for this module.  Raise TreeDataTable.Column undefined when render <TreeDataTable.Column grow={0} basis="300px" renderCell={this.renderIndexColumn} />, thanks anyway.

Comment: Is there an example case for this with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Your module doesn't have a type definition.
You should have install : @types/cp-react-tree-table but apparently it doesn't exist.

So you have to manualy create a file : "cp-react-tree-table.d.ts" containing the types.

You have examples of types definition [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types).